# Drill Down with Ext Cahrts?

Tags: extjs, charts

ExtJS Charts, I am using an Ext column chart and I want to implement some drill down and drill up functionality. How can I do that? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some surfing days in the web I found a solution: Highcharts (at www.highcharts.com, sorry for this I am new in this site so I can only post one link :-( the other link was bigger so...) which is a charting library implemented in js, also there is an [adapter for Ext](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=93669) so the road is quite a bit simple.
The drill-down functionality is not embedded in library but you can handle events related which each series, bar or point in the chart. 
regards